test & train for very very small data
I have just 25 observations. I'm not sure would it possible to test & train the data. For example 15 observations for train and 10 observations for test set. 15 observations is so small for training! I considered permutation feature selection and LOOCV with elastic-net. It left 11 features out of 1000. I used LOOCV in random forest modelling. So I modeled 15 observations with11 features. I got good results but I'm not sure I'm overfitting or not

Hi Leila. Doesn't the answer to this other question of yours https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/651460/164936 already address your new question? How is it different?

Hi, at that time I had 50 observations and I could to test & train. Now, I have to delete the observations with NA values. So I have just 25 observations. I'm not sure would it possible to test & train the data. For example 15 observations for train and 10 observations for test set. 15 observations is so small for training! I considered permutation feature selection and LOOCV with elastic-net. It left 11 features out of 1000.  I used LOOCV in random forest modelling. So I modeled 15 observations with11 features.  I got good results but I'm not sure I'm overfitting or not.

The answer I linked to advised against using feature selection methods, and concluded that you should collect more data or select variables based on theory (so not an algorithm or an automated method). I think the advice still applies. Perhaps other people will have additional recommendations. I'd suggest to edit your question to add all the info you mentioned in your previous comment, as many users of this website overlook comments.

could you please explain more about "select variables based on theory"?
Thanks in advance for your time and help

If there is any document, let me know? Many thanks

It means based on subject matter knowledge, so it requires reviewing existing literature or to consult experts in the domain. To take a simple example, if you want to predict height of people, and you know from other previous studies that gender has an influence on height, it may be relevant to include gender as a feature in your model.

I got it. Thank you very much.

11 features for 15 observations is way too many. 11 features would ordinarily need at least 100 observations. You can try this out by modeling pure noise with 11 features and 15 obs. and seeing what you get.  I agree with @J-J-J

@Leilaali Perhaps you should focus first on fixing the part where "I have to delete the observations with NA values. So I have just 25 observations." Depending on the aim of your analysis (prediction? inference), better techniques than listwise deletion may be available. With 25 observations, every additional observation will help.

A small number of observations means limited information, so you will need to live with the fact that training and testing will be of limited reliability.

@Marjolein Fokkema The aim is prediction. The data is clinical (medical research), and clinical people don't like to do imputation. Is there any other idea?

@Leilaali Mean imputation is bad for inference (hypothesis tests), not for prediction. For inference, multiple imputation important, mostly because it allows to get the variances right. For prediction purposes with penalized regression, mean imputation can work pretty well and has low computational load, see Josse et al. (https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.06931). We found the same in the context of multi-source data (https://doi.org/10.1016/j.inffus.2024.102524), although this is in a different context and our focus was on a dedicated missing data approach for multi-source data.

When undertaking an advanced analysis always ask yourself these questions:

What is the simplest estimation task?
Is my sample size adequate do to this task?

If the answer to the second questions is no, the analysis is futile.  In your case the simplest task is to estimate the overall marginal mean of the response variable Y.  Your sample size is far too small to do that.  So it is far too small to try to estimate mean of Y conditional on a single pre-specified predictor, not to mention a 1000 candidate predictors.
In my experience with binary Y, the minimal sample size for split-sample validation to work (i.e., to be reliable / stable) is around 20,000.  100 repeats of 10-fold cross-validation can work, and you will be very disappointed with the results of this resampling validation on your small dataset.

This answer will not focus on whether variable selection in such a situation makes sense at all, or whether you should really try hard to make more observations available (imputation techniques for missing values may help).
Regarding the overfitting issue, however, in principle LOOCV may be as good as it gets to assess this, however you need to make sure that you don't have information leakage, meaning that you need to run the LOOCV in such a way that the final assessment of your prediction quality is really run on data which has not been used for model selection or dimension reduction at an earlier stage. One way to achieve this is nested cross-validation, i.e., you may want to assess the final prediction quality by an outer cross-validation that leaves one observation at a time out from the complete model selection procedure. If the latter also involves LOO-CV, you need to run this an on inner CV each time on the observations that do not include the one observation left out in the outer CV. (A similar thing can be done with bootstrap.)
As I said this is probably as good as it gets, but with the given number of observations the prediction error estimate may not be very precise anyway.
